# Tomcat closes connection after a month of inactivity - how to avoid?

Tags: java, apache-flex, hibernate, tomcat, blazeds

I have a Flex/Java/MySQL/Hibernate application running on tomcat/BlazeDS which have very LOW activity, the user can even not visit it for months.

The problem that after a month of inactivity the connections between tomcat and mysql are closed and then I need to restart both the mysql and tomcat servers, is there a way to avoid that and maintain the connection always open?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL closes inactive connections after some time. Hibernate in its default configuration will not reconnect. Use the advice here to enable automatic reconnection:

http://www.databasesandlife.com/automatic-reconnect-from-hibernate-to-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you could stop the connection from closing, and I'm not really sure its that good an idea either. [You can set up and use a connection pool on Tomcat](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/04/19/database-connection-pooling-with-tomcat.html) which would automagically reconnect when you request the resource. Some connection pools will also do periodic testing on the live connections, if you configure a certain minimum, in order to see that the database is still responsive as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put a check in the code to see if the connection is closed, and if it is, re-open it?

Or use a connection pool, I think that this would be handled for you automatically. c3p0, bonecp, proxool, dbcp